# How to check if an index in a vector is already used

Tags: c++, vector

How do I check if an index in a vector is already used ?
I want something like this:

```cpp
if(isUsed(vector,index))
    do something
else
    do something else
```

example:

```cpp
std::vector<int> myVector;
myVector[0] = 5;
myVector[2] = 0;
myVector[3] = 1;

myVector.erase(3);

isUsed(myVector,3) = false
isUsed(myVector,1) = false
isUsed(myVector,2) = true
isUsed(myVector,5) = false
isUsed(myVector,0) = true
```

or:

```cpp
std::map<int,std::string> myMap;
myMap[1] = "x";

myMap.count(1) > 0 = true
myMap.count(0) > 0 = false
```

I want this function to be fast because im working with a lot of indexes.

Comment: Use `boost::optional`

Comment: How do you define "used"? All the valid indices (`0` to `size() -1`) have valid elements.

Comment: Are you sure `vector` is the right data structure if you need to do this?

Comment: Your example is flawed in other ways as well, you don't set the size of the vector so all indexing will be out of bounds.

Comment: `myVector.erase(3);` is wrong as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may try an [std::unordered_map](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map), it works like a map, but is much faster for most operations

```
std::unordered_map<int,std::string> myMap;
myMap[1] = "w";

myMap.count(1) > 0 == true
myMap.count(0) > 0 == false
```

Answer (score 0):

Although use boost::optional correct it sounds like you might be asking for something like `std::map<int, Object>`

Answer (score 0):

Use associative array aka `std::map`:

```
std::map<size_t,int> myVector;
myVector[0] = 5;
myVector[2] = 0;
myVector[3] = 1;

myVector.erase(3);
```

and your `isUsed()` will be equal to:

```
myVector.count(3)
```

you can wrap it into function if you want:

```
bool isUsed( const std::map<size_t,int> &m, size_t idx )
{
    return m.count( idx );
}
```

if you do not care on the order you iterate over your container, ytou may use `std::unordered_map` instead, which will be faster, but order of elements in iteration would be pretty much random.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the exact same logic you used when you were explaining your problem in your question. Which is to create a `bool` vector with the exact size of your vector, and then initialize it with `false`s.

Now every time you use an index, you just go to your bool vector and change that index to `true`, means it was used before. You may check each index's value `true || false` to know if that index was used before or not.